# Get data from multiple spinners?

Tags: android, android-spinner

hi am struck with this issue. I have a number of spinners created dynamically.Please help me to get data from these spinners.

When clicking add button should get data from all spinners.

code for button click

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {  
            String[] strings = new String[allEds.size()];
            String[] stringSpinns = new String[allSpns.size()];
            for(int i=0; i < allEds.size(); i++){
                strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();

              try
                {
                        json.put("Name", strings[i]);
                        //json.put("Description", descOfFolder);
                        Log.w("ANDROID DYNAMIC VIEWS:", "View Id: " + json);
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }


        }
    });
}
```

spinner dynamically added with this code

```
public void addSpinner() {

    LinearLayout rAlign = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lId);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Net Banking Id");
    list.add("Net Banking password");
    list.add("Account Number");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    Log.w("ANDROID DYNAMIC VIEWS:", "View Id: " + dataAdapter);       
    LinearLayout spinnerHolder = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    spinnerHolder.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    spinnerHolder.setLayoutParams(
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
        Spinner newSpinner = new Spinner(getApplicationContext());
        allSpns.add(newSpinner);
        newSpinner.setLayoutParams(
            new Spinner.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        newSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        rAlign.addView(spinnerHolder);
        spinnerHolder.addView(newSpinner);
        Log.w("ANDROID DYNAMIC VIEWS:", "View Id: " + allSpns);

  }
```

created list to track number of spinners and opened a loop for to get data.

```
String[] stringSpinns = new String[allSpns.size()];
```

But confused about how to get data ...

Comment: post the code where you are facing problem?

Comment: @ Ram kiran yes updated with the code

Answer (score 0):

It has a simple solution.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    switch(your spinner id)
    {
        case spinnerid:
        Toast.makeText(your context,parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()+"  Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the problem is number of spinners and handling them, you can probably make an array of spinners and then retrive data using a loop in another array. **OR** you can use a constant array of ids and find your spinner using `findViewById(yourSpinnerId)` and then use this spinner to get selected item. To make a constant array of ints you might want to look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) or [here](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r12/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html)

If you are concerned with the selected value of the spinner, use

```
mySpinner.getItemAtPosition(mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition())
```

Also, you can use following methods : `getSelectedItem()`, `getSelectedItemPosition()`, `getSelectedItemId()` or `getSelectedView()` Documentation for these are [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html)